# Android RelativeLayout LayoutParams setMargins(500,500,0,0) Not Effective

Tags: android, imageview, android-relativelayout

I'm working on an Android game.  I'm trying to position an image view away from the top left corner of the screen using margins, but it's not working.

Main Activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getRealSize(size);

    RelativeLayout relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
    );
    relativeLayout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    setContentView(relativeLayout);
    gameView = new GameView(this, this, size.x, size.y);
    relativeLayout.addView(gameView);
...
```

And my GameBoard class:

```
public GameBoard (Activity activity, ...) {
    ...
    revealItemImageView = new ImageView(activity);
    revealItemImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams revealItemLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
        (int)(screenHeight * 0.66), (int)(screenHeight * 0.66));
    revealItemLayoutParams.setMargins(500, 500, 0, 0);
    revealItemImageView.setLayoutParams(revealItemLayoutParams);
    activity.addContentView(revealItemImageView, revealItemLayoutParams);
    revealItemImageView.requestLayout();
```

But the image appears right up in the top left corner with no space between either the top or the left side.  Why?

Comment: Try adding it to the `RelativeLayout` instead

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out.  That, coupled with adding a second content view was just what I needed.  I'm creating an answer so others with this question can see the complete code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The view needed to be added to a relative layout and the relative layout needed to be added as a second content view.

I've put together a code demonstration in its own project.  The two image views both have the appropriate margins and overlap slightly.

Here is the code in its entirety.

```
package com.zzzzzzzz.testrelativelayout;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // layer 1
    RelativeLayout mainActivityContentViewRelativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams mainActivityContentViewLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
    );
    mainActivityContentViewRelativeLayout.setLayoutParams(mainActivityContentViewLayoutParams);
    setContentView(mainActivityContentViewRelativeLayout);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams backgroundLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(100, 100);
    backgroundLayoutParams.setMargins(100, 100, 0, 0);
    ImageView backgroundView = new ImageView(this);
    backgroundView.setImageResource(R.drawable.item_baby_bottle_b);
    backgroundView.setLayoutParams(backgroundLayoutParams);
    mainActivityContentViewRelativeLayout.addView(backgroundView);

    // layer 2
    RelativeLayout secondContentViewRelativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams secondContentViewLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
    );
    secondContentViewRelativeLayout.setLayoutParams(secondContentViewLayoutParams);
    addContentView(secondContentViewRelativeLayout, secondContentViewLayoutParams);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams itemLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(100, 100);
    itemLayoutParams.setMargins(150, 150, 0, 0);
    ImageView itemImageView = new ImageView(this);
    itemImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.item_diamond_ring_a);
    itemImageView.setLayoutParams(itemLayoutParams);
    secondContentViewRelativeLayout.addView(itemImageView);


}
```

}